# Having a problem applying clean urls to subdirectories

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to clean up urls and change filename.php to filename/ everything works fine, but when I try to do it in a sub-directory it tries to check in the parent directory for the file. What do I need to do?

```
    RewriteBase /    

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/favicon.ico" [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/js/" [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/images/" [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/inc/" [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/css/" 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ([A-Za-z0-9_\.\-]+)/$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The php and curl tags are not appropriate for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewriterule doesn't match slashes, so it only takes the last segment of the URL. Add a slash and it will match the entire request path. Or you could just matching against `^.*/$`, if there isn't some reason not to.